# How to fix "couldn't connect to host" error installing Unity Webapps?

Tags: apt, ppa, webapps, add-apt-repository

I get the following errors when I try to install **Unity Webapp on Ubuntu 12.04**:

```
root@detro-X101H:/home/detro# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webapps/preview
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 125, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 80, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (7, "couldn't connect to host")
```

My Internet connection seems to be working fine otherwise. I think I *am* using a proxy server. When I run `apt-get update` as root, I get these error messages ([full output here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1127516/)):

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F1773AF13B1510FD
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8CD60EC948894010
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A45934EA9D4C08B
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C2518248EEA14886
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 32B18A1260D8DA0B
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/launchpad.net/~scopes-packagers/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

[Here's the ouput of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list; for X in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; do echo; echo; echo "** $X:"; echo; cat $X; done`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1127536/) (which lists all enabled software sources).

I'm **new** to Linux, and I will provided more details as needed.

Comment: yes. connection is not a problem

Comment: i think so. and when i try to apt-get update it shows error of no public key avail.

Comment: @eliah kagan: help please

Comment: unable to do so as i dont have much rights and limited to certain word limit.

Comment: apt-get update error: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1127516/

Comment: output for cat /etc/apt/sources.list; for X in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*; do echo; echo; echo "** $X:"; echo; cat $X; done: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1127536/

Comment: @eliah: i'hv posted everything as u hv asked for

Comment: @eliah: reply please

Comment: somebody help please.m unable to install most of the softwares

Answer (score 0):

The best guest is that you were affected by an outage in LaunchPad service or a problem with your network:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webapps/preview
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 This is the preview for Unity WebApps for Ubuntu Quantal (12.10) Precise (12.04).

To install...

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webapps/preview
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-preview
Restart your session (logout and back in)

To uninstall...

sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:webapps/preview
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~webapps/+archive/preview
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
```

As you can see, I'm able to add the repository. The only clue is:

```
curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (7, "couldn't connect to host")
```

This means that the curl library of python, could not get access to the LP servers.